# Call 3rd party with 3rd party URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been given a URL like this

```
http://m.example.com/user/login
```

My teacher told me i have to call this URL and login to it with a username and Password using ajax or Jquery from a completely different website .
It's a web service which does a lot of things and now i'm just have to login to it.
When i call a url it errors like this :

```
http://m.example.com/user/login?u=blah&p=blah
```

Anyone know what should i do ?
 Do i need to do some php ?
 Or it can be done with ajax and html alone?

and i have done this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#id").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://m.example.com/user/login",
       data: "name="+ $('input[name='u']').val() +"&pwd="+ $('input[name='p']').val() , // change the param names according to your teacher
       success: function(response){    
         // do what ever you want with the response
       },
});
```

and html :

```
<form method="post">
 First name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="u" value="blah">
 <br>
 Last name:<br>
 <input type="password" name="p" value="blah">
 <br><br>
 <input type="button" id="id" value="Submit">
```

and the error :

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x207bfd0>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x2238110>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x207bfd0>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x2238190>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

Comment: first you never send username and password in GET request its completely foolishness

Comment: I know i have to use POST , i dont know how

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/url-parser-query-string-splitter.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you sound like a beginner, you should ask a few questions from your teacher.

First ask for the parameter names to be passed to the server where the login service requires.

Then use the following ajax to pass the values to the URL so the the login service is invoked.

```
<form method="post">
 First name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="u" value="blah">
 <br>
 Last name:<br>
 <input type="password" name="p" value="blah">
 <br><br>
 <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://m.example.com/user/login",
       data: "name="+ $('input[name='u']').val() +"&pwd="+ $('input[name='p']').val() , // change the param names according to your teacher
       success: function(response){    
         // do what ever you want with the response
       },
});
```

The form shouldn't contain a submit but rather a button. Add a click event to that button with the ajax. That should make the script run.

The response will either be a JSON with a success or a failure response or else a page redirect. Just do a `console.log(response)` to view what is returning from the server.

Comment: thank you for reply
i have edited the first post and presented the error

Comment: `$(""#id"")` should bt `$("#id")` or else would not work

Comment: yes i have edited and corrected it but the button wont word no matter how many times i click on it :(

Comment: just nothing happens when i click on it

Comment: first, check whether the button actually exists in your page. then open developer tools and add a break-point in the script tab inside the click even and see whether it hits. If it hits, check the console for an ajax response!

Comment: button exits , actually i don't know how to add a break point inside the click and don't know how to check the console for an ajax . if you can just add it to your existing code or give me a resource for these 2 i'll be in your debt greatly :)